# SQL Simple JOIN issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have never used JOINs or have worked with multiple table before.

This error is popping up.

> Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in [pathway to this mysql_query line].

What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

```
$group_id= 4;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT table1.user_facebook_id AS user_facebook_id 
                       FROM table1 JOIN table2
                       ON table1.user_id = table2.user_id 
                       WHERE table2.group_id = $group_id");

$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

Comment: Is this actually your code, or are you assuming that $group_id is 4? That error indicates that where group id should be inserted sql is not finding anything. Maybe try 'WHERE table2.group_id = ".$group_id);'

Comment: it would be helpful if you could post the structure of the tables as well...

Comment: That means the query failed.  Add `if($result) die(mysql_error())`, and see the error it prints.

Comment: WHERE table2.group_id = ".$group_id); has the same error.
Im 99% the structure of my tables isn't the issue here. I have that stuff working perfectly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should test the value of `$result` to see if the query failed. If so, print the error for debugging purposes:

```
 $sql = "SELECT ...";
 $result = mysql_query($sql);
 if (!$result) {
     trigger_error(mysql_error());
 }
```

You may also want to try running the SQL query in the MySQL workbench to see if it works there.

Comment: After trying that this error pops up. Im getting closer!

Notice: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 4 in...[line 'trigger error' is on].

Comment: @RickRyan: What do you get if you run the same query in MySQL Workbench? What do you get if you print the SQL? For example, `echo $sql;` in my above example.

Comment: I use phpMyAdmin. But I ran the query through that and the response says "You have to choose at least one column to display". To give you some more input I have the column user_facebook_id in table1. The column user_id in both table 1 and 2. And the column group_id in table 2. I really appreciate you helping me by the way.

Comment: @RickRyan: I'd concentrate on getting it working in MySQL Workbench / phpMyAdmin first, before trying to correct  your PHP code. If it doesn't work in MySQL, there's  no chance it will work in PHP.